# how to refreh the same page url in angular6 in mvc project

Tags: url, model-view-controller, angular6, page-refresh

```
Imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    SharedModule,
    ContentsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' }),
    MatSnackBarModule,
    BrowserAnimatithe onsModule
}
```

in `app/module.ts`

But the page does not reload. I got `404 error`.
Please help me.

Comment: try calling `this.ngOnInit();` `onClick` of the button.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
when we refresh the page , i need to load same page. for example

how to refreh the same page url in angular6 in mvc project

when we refresh tha above pageURL , same page loaded. so i need like this. hen we refresh i got 404 error.

Please help me.

Comment: basically what you need is to refresh the data and remove any messages and extra data from the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

in `HTML`

```
<button (click)="refresh()"></button>
```

in `TS` file

```
refresh(){
   this.ngOnInit();
}
```

Comment: when we refresh the page using enter button in addresbar (in browser). i cant add "button".

Comment: what do you want to do? please explain, i don't understand.

Comment: we have created the application using MVC with angular6.my application is working fine. but refresh the page , automatically go to start page. if remove hashlocalsrtagy provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy, i got 404 error.

Comment: It is very urgent.

Comment: I got below error   https://localhost:44381/chapters/chapters Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /chapters/chapters

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3160.0

Comment: const AppRoutes: Routes = [


  { path: '', redirectTo: '/chapters/chapters', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'chapters/chapters', component: ChaptersComponent },
  { path: 'chapter1/chapter1', component: Chapter1Component },
 


];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ChaptersComponent,
    Chapter1Component,

Comment: ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    SharedModule,
    ContentsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes),
    MatSnackBarModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    environment.production ? ServiceWorkerModule.register('../ngsw-worker.js') : [],
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatDialogModule
    //,{ onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'}

  ],
  entryComponents:
    [


      



    ],

Comment: exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [SessionService, AuthorizationGuard, { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Comment: tjhis is my app.module.ts

Comment: Dont paste in comment, its is very tough to read. Edit your code and add in there

Comment: I cannot do the chat.

Comment: how to chat here.. i clicked that( automatically move this discussion to chat?). but no response